# Problema con ENUM en JAVA

Tags: java

Buenas el problema que estoy teniendo es que básicamente el programa consiste en un equipo de basketball donde cada jugador tiene una determinada posición en la que juega, para ello definí un `enum`, el tema es que ahora quiero utilizarlo en el constructor pero no puedo.

No se cómo asignarle cada posición a cada jugador que creo.

```
public class Jugador{
  private long cedula;
  private String nombre;
  private int edad;
  private int aniosExperiencia;
  enum posicion{BASE,ESCOLTA,ALERO,ALA_PIVOT,PIVOT};

  public Jugador(String nombre, long cedula , int edad){
      this.nombre=nombre;
      this.cedula=cedula;
      this.edad=edad;
  }

  public Jugador(String nombre, long cedula , int edad, int aniosExperiencia){
    this.nombre=nombre;
    this.cedula=cedula;
    this.edad=edad;
    this.aniosExperiencia=aniosExperiencia;
  }

  public String getNombre(){
    return nombre;
  }

  public int getEdad(){
    return edad;
  } 

  public long getCedula(){
    return cedula;
  }

  public void dimeNombre(String nombre){
    this.nombre=nombre;
  }

  public void dimeEdad(int edad){
    this.edad=edad;
  }

  public void dimeCedula(long cedula){
    this.cedula=cedula;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Un `enum` no es mas que una definición propia de un tipo de variable.

Una vez que defines el mismo, se utiliza como cualquier otra variable.

La ventaja que tiene el mismo, es que los valores que puede tomar ya están predefinidos, y por lo tanto facilitan su uso.

Para usarlo, una vez definido, tenes que definir una variable de ese tipo:

```
posicion PosicionJugador;
```

Y en tu constructor, pasar una variable del tipo del `enum`:

```
public Jugador(String nombre, long cedula , int edad, int aniosExperiencia, posicion pos){
    this.nombre=nombre;
    this.cedula=cedula;
    this.edad=edad;
    this.aniosExperiencia=aniosExperiencia;
    this.PosicionJugador = pos;
}
```

Pero hay algo a tener en cuenta. Si tu `enum` esta definido dentro de la clase, nadie de afuera de la clase lo va a ver. Por lo general los `enum` se definen en otra clase, o por fuera de las mismas, para poder ser utilizados en todos lados.

Para mas información ver [aca](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html)